# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to start my app in Android Studio, it creates 3 errors like these:

Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Games\AndroidSDK\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   [Here is an image of what I see when I try to start the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xuoA.png)

Comment: Show gradle file, please

Answer (score 0):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 24 or higher. Right now, it would appear that your `compileSdkVersion` is below 24, but you are using some resources (e.g., from the Android Support Library) that require a `compileSdkVersion` of 24 or higher.